# Modalverben dürfen/können ohne Vollverb "haben"

Tags: modal-verb

Seit etwa 10 Jahren beobachte ich in meinem Umfeld in Süddeutschland (Bayern), dass die Modalverben "dürfen" und (seltener) "können" häufig ohne das Vollverb "haben" oder ohne ähnliche Verben, die im Kontext passen, verwendet werden. Beispiel:

> Darf ich die Marmelade?

Das ist für mich ungewohnt und der Satz bleibt nach meinem Gefühl in der Luft hängen. Ursprünglich hielt ich diese Entwicklung für eine Unschärfe der Kindersprache, doch auch Erwachsene in meinem Umfeld haben diese Form schon verwendet. Bei Diskussionen wurde die Vermutung geäußert, dass diese Form im nördlichen Teil Deutschlands in der Umgangssprache bereits gängiger ist und diese Entwicklung jetzt auch den südlichen Teil einholt. In der Medienwelt ist mir dieser Trend bisher nicht aufgefallen.

Mich interessiert der Grund für diese Entwicklung. Während viele aktuelle Änderungen des Sprachgebrauchs aus dem Englischen abgeleitet werden können (ich liebe etwas statt ich mag etwas gerne, ich bin gut/fein, usw) ist hier offensichtlich ein anderer Mechanismus am Werk. "May I the marmelade?" wird meines Wissens nach auch in der englischen/amerikanischen Umgangssprache nicht verwendet.

Comment: Das ist in Norddeutschland nicht gängig.

Comment: Würde mal die Vermutung "Gemütlichkeit" in den Raum werfen? Habe ich schon oft gehört (Hessen). Manchmal aber auch konternt: "Darfst du sie was? Essen? Werfen? Kaufen?". Aber diese Nutzung kenne ich schon seit über einem Jahrzehnt. Neu ist die nicht.

Comment: @Janka Harz ist nicht Norddeutschland, lol

Comment: @vectory Ich lebe aber nicht nur im Harz. Außerdem müsste es, würde die These von der Wanderung von Norden nach Süden stimmen, ja im Harz vorbeigekommen sein.

Comment: Das ist mir noch nie untergekommen...

Comment: Ich bin im Raum Berlin/Brandenburg, Sachsen-Anhalt und Mecklenburg-Vorpommern unterwegs und kann die Vermutung zur norddeutschen Herkunft nicht teilen, außer in der Kindersprache bei Fragen wie „Darf ich noch ein Eis/Bonbon/...“

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dieses Phänomen ist deutlich älter und wurde von mir bereits vor rund 50 Jahren beobachtet, und zwar noch weiter im Süden als von dir bemerkt:

Ich wurde 1965 in Graz (Hauptstatt der Steiermark im Südosten Österreichs) geboren, und wurde in den 1970er-Jahren von manchen Erwachsenen dafür gescholten, Sätze wie *»Darf ich noch ein Eis?«* gebildet zu haben.

Ich glaube auch, dass die Urheber solcher Konstruktionen hauptsächlich Kinder sind, die mit Hilfe von Analogien dabei sind, sich die Grammatik der deutschen Sprache anzueignen, und das - wie ich vermute - im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum, ohne großartige geographische Unterschiede. Dass es dann auch Erwachsene gibt, die ebenfalls solche Sätze bilden, ist dann keine große Überraschung.

Mehr als eine These habe ich zwar auch nicht anzubieten, aber vielleicht finden sie andere auch schlüssig:

Die deutsche Modalverben haben nicht nur die Eigenschaft, Notwendigkeiten und Möglichkeiten auszudrücken, sondern sie können auch wie Bewegungsverben verwendet werden:

> Ich soll morgen zum Chef.
> Lisa will in den Garten.
> Hier dürfen nur Mitarbeiter hinein.
> Bei der nächsten Weggabelung müssen Sie nach links.
> Ich möchte endlich nach Hause.

In jedem dieser Sätze gibt es außer einem Modalverb kein anderes Verb, und trotzdem empfinden fast alle deutschen Muttersprachler diese Sätze als vollständig.

Es gibt aber auch andere Konstruktionen, in denen das Modalverb ohne zusätzliches Vollverb existieren kann:

> Hans kann ziemlich gut Latein.
> Das darfst du nicht.
> Ich will genau dieses Brötchen und nicht das dahinter.

Als Kind begreift man in einem bestimmten Stadium des Spracherwerbs vielleicht noch nicht, dass diese Verwendung von Modalverben als Vollverben an bestimmte Bedingungen geknüpft ist. Und es ist tatsächlich auch schwierig zu begründen, wo in der folgenden Reihe der Punkt ist, an dem aus einer akzeptierten Konstruktion eine Konstruktion wird, die man als unvollständig empfindet, und warum es diesen Punkt überhaupt gibt:

> Ich will das nicht.
> Ich will diesen Brötchen.
> Ich will ein Eis.
> Darf ich ein Eis?

In allen vier Sätzen kann ein zusätzliches Vollverb nicht schaden:

> Ich will das nicht machen.
> Ich will diesen Brötchen kaufen.
> Ich will ein Eis essen.
> Darf ich ein Eis essen?

Aber warum das zusätzliche Vollverb bei *»Darf ich ein Eis?«* dringlicher herbeigesehnt wird als bei *»Ich will das nicht«,* ist nicht so einfach festzustellen. Und daher ist es auch kein Wunder, dass verschiedene Personen die Grenze zwischen *notwendig* und *überflüssig* an unterschiedlichen Stellen wahrnehmen und ihre Sätze dann auch entsprechend bilden.

Comment: Also ist meine Wahrnehmung einer "aktuellen Entwicklung" in erster Linie durch die zunehmende Anzahl von Kindern in meinem Umfeld beeinflusst. Beruhigend.

Answer (score 0):

Ist hier (Berlin) keine unübliche Ausdrucksweise, erscheint mir auch nicht regionalbegrenzt zu sagen "Er kann Kung-Fu", "Darf er das?".

Im gegebenen Beispiel ist von der Etymologie aus, die *dürfen* zu *darben* stellt und weiteres ungewiss lässt (DWDS/Pfeifer), durchaus von einem engeren Bezug zum Essen auszugehen. Ob *haben* dafür ursprünglich als Hilfsverb zu zählen sei, bspw. *Erfolg haben*, *er hat erfolg(t)*, oder als Vollverb, vgl. engl. *we are having lunch* (wir halten Mittag?), ist kaum auszumachen.

Insbesondere ist Ungewissheit über die Entstehung des ge-Partizips, dem altfränkisch *ham* entspricht, dass sich auch noch im finnischen Komitativ niederschlägt, bemerkenswert. Zweitens stehen verschieden Herleitungen der ersten Person Singular, **eǵh₂óm (sanskritisch *ahám*, altgriechisch ἐγών "ich") zu Bedenken. Meinem Empfinden nach müsste es wenn überhaupt lauten:

> Darf ich ma die Butter

oder kurz

> Darf ich ma

Alles andere ist unhöflich (:D). Soweit *ma* als Kontraktion von *mal* verunglimpft wird, zählt es zu *Mal*, *Mahl* und veraltet *mahlen*, "wer zu erst kommt ma(h)lt zuerst", insofern macht das immer noch Sinn und *haben* wäre ganz gewiss hyperkorrekt (bestenfalls wäre mit *(ha)bedarf zu rechen, wie andere Ableitungen mit *-darf, -durf, -dürf*). Ob man das auf Mittelbairisch anders sieht spielt keine Geige. Wenn man behaupten will, diese Ausdrucksweise wäre neu, müsste zuerst ausgeschlossen sein, dass es nicht als archaisches Überbleibsel überlebt hat, dort wo noch *ihm* für *sie* steht.

Dementsprechend ist "? darfimia die Butter" in bairisch zu erwarten.

Ferner sind Schweizerisches Idiotikon und bspw. Schmellers Bairisches Wörterbuch zu befragen. Das mag vorerst dahi stehen, da der Fragesteller in Vorleistung zu gehen hätte.

---

Kurz gesagt ich glaube nicht, dass es auf die Frage eine einfache Antwort gibt. Die Beobachtung des Fragestellers ist wahrscheinlich ein Fall von *[Recency illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_illusion)*.